# Logging in and registration in the pop-up/module on all pages in magento, excluding the login and registration page

Tags: magento2, javascript, login, popup, registration

I created an overwrite path in `app/design/frontend/<name_vendor>/default/Magento_Customer/frontend/web/template/authentication-popup.html`

Here I understand that I can change the texts.
Where can I trigger a pop-up on all pages except login / registration?
If someone logs in, pop up cannot appear.

Invokes it in the console: `jQuery('.block-authentication').modal('openModal');`

Answer (score 0):

- Step 1: Add block in default.xml  with template login.phtml
- Step 2: Check exclude url "Logging in and registration page" in function tohtml of block class()
- Step 3: Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/templates/form/login.phtml

```
<div class="block block-customer-login" id="popup-modal" >
<div class="block-title">
    <strong id="block-customer-login-heading" role="heading" aria-level="2"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Registered Customers')) ?></strong>
</div>
<div class="block-content" aria-labelledby="block-customer-login-heading">
    <form class="form form-login"
          action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getPostActionUrl()) ?>"
          method="post"
          id="login-form"
          data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
        <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
        <fieldset class="fieldset login" data-hasrequired="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('* Required Fields')) ?>">
            <div class="field note"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('If you have an account, sign in with your email address.')) ?></div>
            <div class="field email required">
                <label class="label" for="email"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Email')) ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input name="login[username]" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getUsername()) ?>" <?php if ($block->isAutocompleteDisabled()) : ?> autocomplete="off"<?php endif; ?> id="email" type="email" class="input-text" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Email')) ?>" data-mage-init='{"mage/trim-input":{}}' data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field password required">
                <label for="pass" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Password')) ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input name="login[password]" type="password" <?php if ($block->isAutocompleteDisabled()) : ?> autocomplete="off"<?php endif; ?> class="input-text" id="pass" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Password')) ?>" data-validate="{required:true}">
                </div>
            </div>
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('form_additional_info') ?>
            <div class="actions-toolbar">
                <div class="primary"><button type="submit" class="action login primary" name="send" id="send2"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Sign In')) ?></span></button></div>
                <div class="secondary"><a class="action remind" href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getForgotPasswordUrl()) ?>"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Forgot Your Password?')) ?></span></a></div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(
        [
            'jquery',
            'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
        ],
        function(
            $,
            modal
        ) {
            var options = {
                'type': 'popup',
                'title': 'your popup title',
                'modalClass': 'your_popup_custom_class',
                'responsive': true,
                'innerScroll': true,
                'buttons': [{
                    text: $.mage.__('Back'),
                    class: 'back_button_class',
                    click: function () {
                        this.closeModal();
                        // any javascript coode
                    }
                }]
            };

        $(document).ready(function(){
            var popup = modal(options, $('#your_popup_container')); 
            $("#your_popup_container").modal("openModal");
        });
    }
);
```